# inserting multiline text into Google Big Query

Tags: text, google-bigquery

I have .txt file that was given to me.  The file has two columns:

```
ID         | DESCRIPTION
========================
STRING     | MULTI_LINE STRING
```

so the problem I have is this large text file contains multilines as it goes from record to record.

Example:

```
548f8c9d4b78987b76f86018|facebook|I am a complete description.  Please see what I like below:

-Cars
-Trains
-Computers

I also like Star Trek
w6nc1y0afl2jo3zo9z7jvpo|facebook|I am another description.  HI!
```

How do I get the multi-line into GBQ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first translate this file into JSON format.

New line can be encoded as `\n` character.

Then [load JSON from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json) or [load from local file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local) into a table.

Sample JSON file:

```
{"id":"1","first_name":"John\nsecond line"}
{"id":"2","first_name":"Jane\nsecond line"}
```

Result table

```
+-------------+----+
| first_name  | id |
+-------------+----+
| John        |  1 |
| second line |    |
| Jane        |  2 |
| second line |    |
+-------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

This will load the files into BigQuery, but only if you manually add quotes `"` to the multiline sentences:

```
bq load --allow_quoted_newlines -F "|" dataset.table file.tsv "a,b,c"
```

The modified file looks like this:

```
i|i|i
548f8c9d4b78987b76f86018|facebook|"I am a complete description.  Please see what I like below:

-Cars
-Trains
-Computers

I also like Star Trek"
w6nc1y0afl2jo3zo9z7jvpo|facebook|I am another description.  HI!
```

And BigQuery will read that well:

[image]

Comment: You add them :/